# CMake error when building. Project uses boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, compiler-errors, cmake

I've downloaded samples to run in a open source simulator written in c++. I'm following [this](https://github.com/golems/grip/wiki/Linux-installation) tutorial to help me build and run the samples. I've completed most of the commands in the tutorial. But when I try to cmake (which is one of last steps in the tutorial), I get this error.

Here's the sample I'm trying to run: https://github.com/golems/grip-samples/tree/master/cubesTab

The error I get is here:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package):
  Could not find module FindDARTExt.cmake or a configuration file for package
  DARTExt.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find FindDARTExt.cmake or set DARTExt_DIR to
  the directory containing a CMake configuration file for DARTExt.  The file
  will have one of the following names:

    DARTExtConfig.cmake
    dartext-config.cmake



CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1202 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.46.1

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_system
          boost_filesystem

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindDART.cmake:50 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:31 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Have you installed the named Boost development packages? How about DART?

Comment: Dart has been installed. When I installed grip, I believe it has installed DART. I installed boost with the following commands:

sudo apt-get install libboost-system1.46.1

sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem1.46.1

Comment: You need the _development_ packages, they are the ones with `-dev` in their name.

Comment: It fixes the boost-system and boost-filesystem errors. The first error: "Could not find module FindDARTExt.cmake or a configuration file for package
  DARTExt."

still exists

Comment: You can search file FindDARText.cmake in google, and adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/path/to/findDARTExt, or ask contributors of this project to include this file in repository

Answer (score 0):

Try to complete the process using:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake libblkid-dev e2fslibs-dev libboost-all-dev libaudit-dev
```